# No value given for one or more of the required parameters c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oledbdatareader

The above-mentioned exception is thrown by visual studio when I run the result of this code's compilation :

```
requete = @"select v.[*] from Visite v, Infirmière i where v.[code_inf] = i.[code_inf]" /* +
           " and i.[nom_inf]='" + nom + "'" +
           " and i.[prenom_inf]='"+prenom+"'"+
           " and v.[date_visite]=to_date('" + d.ToString().Substring(0, 10)+"','DD/MM/YYYY')" */
           ;
MessageBox.Show(requete);


OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(requete, connec);

OleDbDataReader dr = dbc.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read())
{
    dgv_res.Rows.Add(dr.Read());
}
```

`dgv_res` is a datagridview component, and `connec` is an open connection.

I commented a part of my request to see if there was a SQL mistake in it but I really don't see what's wrong in the first line and I keep on getting this exception. I've checked the columns and tables names many times.

This

> no value given for one or more of the required parameters

is thrown where I create the `OleDbDataReader` I think.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Break it down until you find your problem. Does `SELECT * FROM Visite` work?

Comment: Sometimes this error can be thrown due to a syntax error in the query.  Have you tried executing this statement in a SQL tool?  Are any errors thrown, or does it execute correctly?

Comment: Or add a parameter with value to your `OleDbCommand` and see where it's replacing exactly :)

Comment: "Select * from visite" does work, and I have my database as an mbd file so I'm not quite sure how to use requests on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AFAIK*, you can't use `[]` with `*` and since OLE DB provider does not care named parameters, it *may* think this `[*]` is a parameter and  expect a parameter value for it.

If everything is okey other than that, this should work;

```
@"select v.* from Visite v, Infirmière i where v.[code_inf] = i.[code_inf]"
```

With `[*]`, database engine thinks you have a column name called `*` *exactly*, not all columns in `v` table.

Comment: I didn't think this could be as simple as that but it works now ! Thanks a lot :)